# React Native app working on simulator but not on a android device

Tags: android, react-native, aws-amplify

I made a react-native app which was running smoothly on the android simulator as well as Ios simulator.Later on when I made a debug apk and tried to test it on my device but it was showing the following error in the pic.

[image]

```
"dependencies": {
   "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.2",
   "aws-amplify": "^1.1.6",
   "react": "16.5.0",
   "react-native": "^0.57.1",
   "react-native-paper": "^2.1.3",
   "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.0.2",
   "react-navigation": "^2.18.0",
   "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^0.4.0",
   "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
   "redux": "^4.0.0",
   "redux-promise": "^0.6.0"
 },
```

Comment: It is not signed apk error, if you have installed signed apk it will directly crash instead of showing error. If you have installed debug apk, please connect your device with the system.

Comment: Sorry I have installed debug apk only but it shows this error

Comment: It clearly means either your server is not running or device is not properly connected with system.

Comment: Is that issue with some dependencies like redux promise or aws-amplify because my other apps were working fine

Comment: Either you build a release apk, or you plug your device and enable usb debug in your device settings. Or, you hit 'dismiss' in the bottom left corner, and just ignore the message

Answer (score 0):

Connect phone and server on same network,
then run

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

and restart app.

Answer (score 0):

Both the android device and your system should be connected to same network.
Simple way is to connect your phone's hotspot to the system.

Comment: Do the app even depend on the system after we a build a app-debug.apk?Before this also I deployed a app on phone but there was no such problem.It was even working without being on the same network as my system

Comment: app-debug is system dependent, system act as a server.
app-release is the system independent one.

Comment: When I tried with app-release.apk it was crashing everytime.

Comment: Run react-native server in a terminal when creating Release apk
Did you try that?